# jQuery: 'Capital sharp S' (ẞ) instead of auto generated 'SS' for text-transform: uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, character

I start with an example:

In german, the words "Buße" and "Busse" have different meanings (repentance and buses/busses). Both words would be transformed into "BUSSE" if I'm using them on my website with the css definition "text-transform: uppercase".

I'd like to avoid this scenario by using the beautiful "Latin capital letter sharp s" (ẞ) in my uppercase headlines. Because there is no possibility to handle this via CSS, I've wrote a little jQuery snipped that solve this.

```
jQuery( 'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, td, span' ).each( function() {
    if ( jQuery( this ).css( 'text-transform' ) === 'uppercase' ) {
        $( this ).html( $( this ).html().replace( /ß/g, 'ẞ' ) );
    } 
} );
```

This goes trough all the listed elements and check for each, if there is the problematic css property. If true, it replaces the lowercase ß with the uppercase ẞ.

This is working. But the performance of course.. You can imagine.

Is there any other way to do this, or is it possible to optimize this jQuery script with better selector or anything?

Im thankful for any help.

Comment: Does this problematic could appear in all h1, h2, h3, etc. Of your page? Or it can be only in certain cases? Because you could use a class and select by the class and not the whole HTML elements.

Comment: Also in performance, Im not sure if it is better to check if the character "ß" exists in the current HTML before doing the replace.

Comment: Thank you, @BrankVictoria. Both hints are useful. I think I can limit the selector to h1, h2 and .menu-item. Covering the whole thing into an if statement is also a smart solution. I'll do this but hopefully there are some more things I can do to optimize this.